# Where is the equivalent of HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode in .Net Core 1.1?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-mvc

I have found myself in need of scrubbing javascript out of comments being added by users in a .Net Core MVC application. In previous frameworks, this could be achieved by first passing your string into JavaScriptStringEncode.

```
var comment = HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(model.Comment);
```

However, I haven't been able to find the equivalent in .net core.

Comment: You can use the same method just by calling it by it's parents:
@System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(YourStringHere)

Answer (score 25):

Here is an equivalent of `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode` in .net core:

```
using System.Text.Encodings.Web; //part of System.Text.Encodings.Web nuget package
...

var encodedText = JavaScriptEncoder.Default.Encode("TextToEncode");
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a [helper](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/ViewFeatures/JsonHelper.cs) available as `@Json.Serialize` in the views. That uses JSON.Net, taking into account any formatting options configured in Startup.cs:

```
var foo = @Json.Serialize(model);
```

Bear in mind this **does not XSS-sanitizes the json by default**! However you can use an overload that lets you do that, specifying the [`StringEscapeHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_StringEscapeHandling.htm) option of JSON.Net as `EscapeHtml`:

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json

...

var foo = @Json.Serialize(model, new JsonSerializerSettings { StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml });
```

You can maybe wrap that into your own helper like `@Json.SafeSerialize` or `@SafeJson.Serialize`.

I haven't found a better way than your own helpers without forcing the default JsonOutputFormatter to behave this way through the json options in Startup:

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(opts => opts.SerializerSettings.StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml)
```

The problem with the latter approach (and why you might prefer the custom helper) is that it would also affect the JSONs returned from your APIs.

PS. I have raised this on [github](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5949).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the same method, use it like this example on razor:

```
@System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(YourStringHere)
```

**UPDATE:**

As @Dai said, this will only work if you're targeting .NET Framework, which is descouraged with ASP.NET Core.

Comment: This does not work in .NET Core because `System.Web.dll` is unavailable. This will only work in ASP.NET Core if you're targeting .NET Framework instead of .NET Core and if your project references `System.Web.dll` (which is discouraged with ASP.NET Core).

Comment: This does work perfectly in latest Core releases

Comment: @AlexfromJitbit Yeah, it seems since ASP.NET Core 3.x was released that [Microsoft has resurrected `System.Web.dll` as an almost entirely empty assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web?view=net-6.0) containing nothing except a small number of utility types and methods - such as `HttpUtility` and... that's it.

Comment: Seems to be present in .NET 6.0 again.